# htaccess rewrite rules to convert the end of a domain to something else

Tags: .htaccess

I need to have a rewrite rule that will take a username at the end of a domain name and convert it so a $GET statement in my php can read it.

Example:

Someone uses this URL:  http://example.com/randyt

The rewrite rule converts that to: http://example.com/?aff=randyt

Of course it needs to work if they have the www. in front as well.
This way I can have a $GET statement in my php script to pick up what $aff is equal to and I can then find them in my database.

Please be as basic as you can in your answer as I have no idea about htaccess stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) ?aff=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: That works great but now I have another problem. I need to still be able to use the generic link that the script uses as well. http://www.example.com/members/aff/go/randyt  when I try that link it erases it and goes to just http://www.example.com so is there something I can add to that so it will not rewrite that link or any other links that have /members/ in it?

Comment: @RandyThomas: I would suggest opening a new question rather than asking a new question from comments so that you can get better answer.